# Android: how to use CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I have a database, a `ListView`, and a `CustomCursorAdapter` that extends `CursorAdapter`. A menu button adds an item to the database. I want the `ListView` to update and show this change. Normally it doesn't show this new item until i go to the homescreen and reopen the application.

I did eventually get it to work by calling `cursor.requery()` or `mCustomCursorAdapter.changeCursor(newCursor)` whenever I added a new item, but when I set autoRequery to false in the `CursorAdapter` constructor, it worked just the same. Why does it update correctly when autoRequery is set to false?

Am I using `CursorAdapter` correctly? What is the standard way of keeping the list updated with the database? And what does autoRequery do?

Comment: @randzero means that you want to update the listview items whenever new item is added in database, is it right ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The idiomatic and imho correct way to automatically update `Cursor`s is to call [`Cursor#setNotificationUri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#setNotificationUri%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri%29) when they are created and before they are handed off to whatever requested them. Then call [`ContentResolver#notifyChange`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) when anything in that `Cursor`'s Uri's namespace changes.

For example, suppose you were creating a simple mail application and you wanted to update when new mail arrived but also provide various views on the mail. I'd have some basic Uri's defined.

```
content://org.example/all_mail
content://org.example/labels
content://org.example/messages
```

Now, say I wanted to get a cursor that gave me all mail and be updated when new mail arrives:

```
Cursor c;
//code to get data
c.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), Uri.parse("content://org.example/all_mail");
```

Now new mail arrives so I notify:

```
//Do stuff to store in database
getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://org.example/all_mail", null);
```

I should also notify all the `Cursor`s that selected for labels this new message met

```
for(String label : message.getLabels() {
  getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://org.example/lables/" + label, null);
}
```

And also, maybe a cursor is viewing that one specific message so notify them as well:

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://org.example/messages/" + message.getMessageId(), null);
```

The `getContentResolver()` calls happen where the data is accessed. So if it's in a `Service` or `ContentProvider` that is where you `setNotificationUri` and `notifyChange`. You should not be doing that from where the data is accessed, e.g., an `Activity`.

[`AlarmProvider`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/alarmclock/AlarmProvider.java;h=5849a384f0b94259bc6713b9f11cf1c9749ed4ca;hb=062d863a156a3564a839ab5a718f31500298635f) is a simple `ContentProvider` that uses this method to update `Cursor`s.

Comment: This post is really great! Helped me a lot as well on my search! :)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong `Cursor#setNotificationUri` updates the cursor with the latest data whenever their is a `getContentResolver().notifyChanged` is a called in `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Could you please clarify, will automatically update data when you notify change or you need to do anything else in Cursor/CursorAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

I created next method for ListView updating:

```
/**
 * Method of refreshing Cursor, Adapter and ListView after database 
 * changing
 */
public void refreshListView() {
    databaseCursor = db.getReadableDatabase().query(
            CurrentTableName, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            "title"+SortingOrder);
    databaseListAdapter = new DomainAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
            databaseCursor, 
            new String[] {"title", "description"}, 
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
    databaseListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    DomainView.setAdapter(databaseListAdapter);
}
```

end calls it each time after some changing in database