# How to get values from database[Cursor Adapter] and store it to an array in java?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, arrays

I would like to get the values from database of a particular column by executing a query. Is it possible to do it after we do it to the Cursor Adapter or can we attain the values well before itself. Kindly help on this with a snippet or a guide.

Comment: See it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544913/android-how-to-use-cursoradapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
final DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(context);
...
...
db.createDataBase();
..
...try catch logic etc
....
final Cursor c = db.getAllRows();
....
c.getString(4) // String value of 5th Column in Database
```

Cursor Adapter to Array

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
c.moveToFirst(); 
while(!c.isAfterLast()) { 
     mArrayList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME)); 
     c.moveToNext(); 
}
```

DataBaseHelper class has following

```
public Cursor getAllRows() 
    {
        return myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_NAME,
                KEY_YEAR,
                     KEY_QUOTE,
                     KEY_REF}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }
```